# DOS 6.22/Windows 98 encryption software

Tags: encryption, cryptography, dos

Is there any encryption software (full disc encryption or container mode) available for Windows 98? Same question for plain DOS 6.22. Maybe it's strange, but for some reasons I need software like that.

Comment: Do you need "only" something that can take a folder and produce an encrypted version of it from some password or do you need something more sophisticated that actually does on-the-fly decryption / encryption and allows the container / volume to be "normally mounted"?

Comment: Well, I do not conceal that the option with encryption on the fly with "normally mounted volume" would be much better.

Comment: run them in a VM under a proper OS and encrypt *that* file system.

Comment: you may find the answer on [retrocomputing.se]. But even if you can encrypt that, it's easy to break on a system that's such ancient and wasn't built with security in mind. Processes aren't protected from each other in Win 98 so it's even easier to write a program to read the decrypted data. Same to DOS

Comment: About the best you could do is password and encrypt a ZIP file or similar.  None of the modern encryption sweets were written for DOS so any encryption you did have would be trivial to break.  DOS is also limited to 2gb per partition another stumbling block.